# bash program read array

Tags: arrays, linux, bash

I am trying to run a bash program that takes a few command line input names, and then take an array as a command line input.

I.e.,

```
#!/bin/bash
name1=$1
name2=$2
my_array_input=("dog" "cat" "lion")
```

In this example I have name1 and name2 as input, and my_array_input is declared and set inside the script.

In my real script, I'd like to also have name1 and name2 as $1 and $2, but I'd also like to be able to take from the user a (unknown size/ variable size) my_array_input.  The user could input arrays of different lengths, and with his own name of animals as he wish...

Note that all inputs should be command line inputs.

Is there a trick to do this using bash scripting?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The arguments to a Bash script (or any program in Unix-like operating systems) are just a list of strings, so there's no way to do *exactly* what you describe.

However, you can set `name1` to the first argument, `name2` to the second argument, and `my_array_input` to *all subsequent* arguments:

```
#!/bin/bash
name1="$1"
name2="$2"
my_array_input=("${@:3}")
```

If the arguments to the above script are `foo bar dog cat lion`, then `name1` will be `foo`, `name2` will be `bar`, and `my_array_input` will be the array `(dog cat lion)`.